# Subfloat under each other

Tags: vertical-alignment, subfloats

I want to put two subfloat figures under each other but they keep being beside each other. This is the script used:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\subfloat[A]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{a}\label{a}}
\subfloat[B]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{b}\label{b}}
\caption{abc} 
\label{abc}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Just leave an empty line between the two `\subfloat` lines. You may want to add `\centering` just below `\begin{figure}[t]` (which should better be `\begin{figure}[tp]`).

Comment: Too localized?  Hmm.  Apparently, I too was in this particular geographic area, moment in time, and narrow situation.  There *are* wormholes!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Putting a `\newline` between the two subfloats did the trick. Nevermind.